# Paypal rest sdk 400 error (node.js) Something about VALIDATION ERROR (The error is written in description)

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is the error I get

```
name: 'VALIDATION_ERROR',
  details: [
    {
      field: 'purchase_units[0]',
      issue: 'Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified)'
    }
  ],
  message: 'Invalid request - see details',
  information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors',
  debug_id: '74ac8660674d8',
  httpStatusCode: 400
```

This is my /pay post route

```
app.post('/pay' , (req , res) => {

    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart)
    
    
    const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/failed"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": getItems(cart.items)
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": cart.totalPrice
        },
        "description": "This is the payment description."
    }]
};
```

This is the getItems function

```
function getItems(cart) {
    let itemsArray = [];
    for (const [idx, item] of Object.entries(cart)) {
      itemsArray.push({
                "name": item.item.product_name, 
                "price": item.price,
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": item.qty
            });
    }
    return itemsArray;

}
```

When I console.log the cart.totalPrice it is correct as it should be (Which is the total of all the items in the cart) Any idea what is going wrong here. I am a bit new to all this stuff so a bit confused

Comment: Log your actual request JSON, as that will show what the problem is. Something is missing or not adding up, such as an amount total field. You're using a deprecated API

Comment: Can you please provide me with a link of an API that is not deprecated ? I do not know where to find one, I used a youtube video for that API @PrestonPHX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current (non-deprecated) APIs, see examples in [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/)

Make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the current JS SDK frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server